# How to convert nonce to string?

Tags: ios, passkit, apple-wallet

How do i convert certificates, nonce and nonceString data to a String? When i try to convert the nonce, nonceSigntaute to string with UTF8 encoding it's failing.

```
func addPaymentPassViewController(_ controller: PKAddPaymentPassViewController, 
    generateRequestWithCertificateChain certificates: [Data], 
    nonce: Data, 
    nonceSignature: Data, 
    completionHandler handler: @escaping (PKAddPaymentPassRequest) -> Void) {

  ...
}
```

Comment: Did you download root CA to validate the chain? Apple root CA can be obtained from the certificate authority. Below is the link to get the Apple root CA, apple.com/appleca/AppleIncRootCertificate.cer

Comment: @SreedharS, can you please help me, what steps to be followed after installing the certificate?

Comment: How did you solve it?